# C error : Invalid operands binary expression ('float **' and 'float')

Tags: c

I have this code (http://pastebin.com/aWTsGDFW) when Im trying build it I have error Invalid operands binary expression ('float **' and 'float') in the line "*amount = &amount + productPrice;" in the addToAmount action. Anyone help me? Thanks!

The relevant code is pasted below:

```
void addToAmount (float *amount, float price, int qtt, char promo, float VAT){

    float productPrice;

    productPrice = 0.0;

    if (promo == PROMO_NONE){
        productPrice = computeNoPromoPrice(price, qtt, VAT);
    }else{
        if(promo == PROMO_3x2){
            productPrice = computeNxMPromoPrice(3, 2, price, qtt, VAT);
        }else{
            if(promo == PROMO_2x1){
                productPrice = computeNxMPromoPrice(2, 1, price, qtt, VAT);
            }else{
                productPrice = computeHalfPromoPrice (price, qtt, VAT);
            }
        }
    }

    *amount = &amount + productPrice; // <- error here
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages on how to ask questions. Specifically, it is against Stack Overflow rules to link to external code without also having code in the question itself.

Comment: `*amount = *amount + productPrice;`

Comment: did you try `*amount += productPrice;`?

Comment: Or also *amount = `*amount + productPrice`. Google about the difference between a pointer and a reference.

Comment: Amadan sorry I'll keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a double `float` pointer to a `float` value and that doesn't make sense:

```
*amount = &amount + productPrice;
```

you should change that line to

```
*amount += productPrice; // Equivalent to *amount = *amount + productPrice;
```

And also: you should post the code in your question correctly formatted.

Comment: Thanks! it works with *amount += productPrice; too!!

Answer (score 0):

```
*amount = &amount + productPrice;
```

Is the equivalent of saying that the float that is pointed to by amount is equal to the memory address of amount plus the productPrice.

```
*amount = *amount + productPrice;
```

seems to be what you are trying to do.